# Can i run LibGDX inside IOS app using codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Hello i am looking forward to convert my android app which runs libgdx in a fragment to IOS

So i am looking for a way to run libgdx inside IOS app.

For example when i switch to a screen in ios Libgdx instance will run on that screen. I am not talking about converting a standalone libgdx game to ios(like using robovm)

I know i can rewrite android app part of my application using codenameone but i am not sure about libgdx nor how

can i do what i want with codenameone ? is there any guide ? if i can do i will subscribe and start converting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't currently possible as I mentioned in the [reddit thread here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/xfbhtm/can_i_run_libgdx_inside_ios_app_using_codenameone/). I don't think there's a technical blocker but it would require a lot of work and there's no motivation to do that work either from our side or the LibGDX side.